# What is the Runtime and Space Complexity of this program?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

**Problem Statement:** Reverse the words.

**Example:** perfect makes practice
**Output:**  practice makes perfect

I am pretty sure the space complexity is O(n) as I am using StringBuilder but still I wanna be sure.
I am learning Runtime complexity and from below I learned that both loops are running for O(n) elements.
strB.toString() it internally copies the characters and returns the String which I think is also an O(n) task.
The same goes for strB.append(arr[i]) as when the StringBuilder capacity got exhausted it will again call Arrays.copyOf and will create new Character array internally which I think is still O(n).

I am trying to learn run-time and space complexity but sometimes get stuck.
I think this whole solution runtime complexity is O(n2), please let me know your views.

Follow up question:
If it is O(n2) then it means that we can't use java internal DS methods for solving interview questions?

```
public class CharReverseAsWords {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = { 'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ', 'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' ', 'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't',
            'i', 'c', 'e' };
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Creating Stack.
    Deque<String> stk = new ArrayDeque<>();

    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder(26);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //O(n)
        if (arr[i] != ' ') {
            strB.append(arr[i]);           //O(n): If capacity is consumed, new array will get created which has O(n) time complexity.
        } else {
            stk.push(strB.toString());      //O(1)
            stk.push(" ");                  //O(1)
            strB = new StringBuilder(26);
        }
    }

    //pushing last string
    stk.push(strB.toString());          //O(1)

    while (!stk.isEmpty()) {            //O(n)
        System.out.print(stk.pop());    //O(1)
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime + " ms");
}}
```

Comment: Added the Actual problem statement, I think here I am simply asking for Runtime and Space complexity.

Comment: I don't completely follow your code, which seesm overly-complicated to me, but `O(n)` for both space and runtime complexity seems right for this problem.

Comment: What about strB.toString(), strB.append() they internally copies the array which is also an O(n) and this will be happening inside other O(n) loop, which I think is O(n2)?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, it would be `O(n)+O(n)+O(n) = O(3n)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //O(n)
    // ---- //
}

//pushing last string
stk.push(strB.toString());          //O(n)

while (!stk.isEmpty()) {            //O(n)
    System.out.print(stk.pop());
}
```

But, when we calculate complexity with `n` inputs, **constants would not affect much**. That means, `O(3n)` would be `O(n)` by ignoring constants.

Answer 1 : Your programme's Time complexity is `O(n)`

Answer 2 : There are trade-offs between both. We can use collection framework methods of java in DS problems. But, always we need to think if we can achieve the same with our logic and loop, we should go for that. We can take care of not generating more `garbage objects`, `more computation than necessary` and `breaking loops as soon as possible` kind of points of optimisations. If we go for collection framework, these points may be considered as trade-offs.

A little optimisation in your code would be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //O(n)
    // ---- //

    // On last iteration, we can push last string 
    if(i == arr.length - 1) {
        //pushing last string
        stk.push(strB.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I am much more clear but I have 1 more question, I have heard if there is loop and inside it some other loop computation is happening then it is multiplied, let say loop within a loop is O(n) * O(n) =O(n2), similarly strB.toString() and strB.append() internally using Arrays.copy, so don't you think this is also a loop type operation. so O(n) is the main loop then inside it strB.toString() operation is also O(n) which results in O(n2) right ? Can you please explain this

Comment: If nested loops are there, like `for(int i = 0; i < A; i++) { for(int j = 0; i < B; j++) { } }`, it'll have time complexity as `O(A*B)`. The `strB.toString()` and `strB.append()` are not nested calls, but parallel calls, so the complexity would be sum of both like `O(n+n) = O(2n)` which becomes `O(n)` by ignoring constant

Answer (score 0):

This is complexity. 
That's why

```
// time: O(N)
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

// space: O(N)
char[] arr
Deque<String> stk
```

Comment: What about strB.toString(), strB.append() they internally copies the array which is also an O(n) and this will be happening inside other O(n) loop, which I think is O(n2)?

Comment: @AtishayJain You know O(2N) -> O(N), O(26 * N) -> O(N); const number is only O(1) -> O(1 * N) -> O(N)